# What is the difference between \cs_new_eq:NN and \cs_gset_eq:NN?

Tags: expl3, latex3, programming

What is the difference between `\cs_new_eq:NN` and `\cs_gset_eq:NN`, defined in section "Copying control sequences" of [The LaTeX3 Interfaces](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) manual (which is section 4.3.4 on p. 19 of the current version, versioned as *2022-12-17*) as follows.

[image: The documentation re \cs_new_eq and \cs_gset_eq]

The difference between `\cs_new:Nn` and `\cs_gset:Nn` defined in the preceding section is clear: the former aborts the execution of the TeX engine when the function has already been defined, whereas the latter redefines the function silently.

But the difference between `\cs_new_eq:NN` and `\cs_gset_eq:NN` is unclear to me.

Comment: the difference is as you describe for the `n` version, the `new` declaration checks it is new

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By which you mean that the `...new...` declaration will abort execution iff the first of its two arguments has already been assigned a value (any value, not necessarily the same value as the one assigned to its second argument)?

Comment: yes of course you are declaring  new variable, the second argument whether `N` or `n` gives the initial value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `\cs_new...` functions check whether the function to be defined doesn't exist and fail with error otherwise.

To the contrary, the `\cs_(g)set...` functions do no such check.

Contrary to variables, functions needn't be declared in advance, but it's better programming style making sure that functions that we need later to `set` to different meaning already have a definition, maybe just `\scan_stop:` or, probably better, to do nothing.

Note that `\cs_new...` always defines the function at the outermost level, but `\cs_set...` only does a definition valid in the current scope.

Why are there functions `\cs_gset...`, then?

Because sometimes it's needed to change the value of some function at the global level, but likely these will be internal functions (name starting with `__`), not public ones because public functions need to have a well-defined meaning. The kernel must then have a method for doing such a global redefinition.

An example of usage is with `\tl_map_inline:nn`, where a scratch function is defined using the nesting level in its name and the second argument to `\tl_map_inline:nn` as replacement text. Such scratch function *must* be defined at the outermost level, or its job could not be done correctly. However, the programmer using `\tl_map_inline:nn` need not know the name of this scratch control sequence; better yet, they *must* ignore it, because it's an implementation detail that might even change in the future without notice (but how `\tl_map_inline:nn` works will not change). Using `\cs_gset_protected:cpn` for this scratch function is therefore perfectly safe (if programmers stick to the recommended naming practices).

So, is there a difference between `\cs_new_eq:NN` and `\cs_gset_eq:NN`? Yes, a big difference. The former is safe, the latter should be used with due care.